# Is jaundiced just the same as jealous?

Tags: vocabulary

I learned that word from a vocabulary builder app. Since the app only provides a limited definition and sometimes the definition doesn't match with the example,  I'll give the example myself:

> I'm **jaundiced** towards him! He's 10cm taller than me!

Can I use jaundiced that way? This word is kind of uncommon in my view because I've never heard of it. If this question is answered, I hope there will be an explanation about the difference just to make sure I'm using it correctly.

And the reason I'm asking this is that some dictionaries (with limited entries) translated jaundiced as a disease. And it sounds awkward. That's why I want to make sure.

Comment: The full OED defines it as *To affect with jaundice; **usually figurative.** To affect with envy or jealousy; to tinge the **views or judgement** of.* They only have 2 citations for the usage, and the most recent is **1867** - *She..wanted to crush the young lady, and **jaundice her mother**, with a girl twice as brilliant.* But it certainly sounds "awkward / unusual" to me, so I suggest learners should avoid ***jaundiced towards*** in favour of ***jealous of*** (but ***having a jaundiced view*** of something is fine by me).

Comment: ...compare [*His opinion is **coloured***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22his+opinion+is+coloured%22), which almost always implies *affected **negatively***, and is generally equivalent to *He has a **jaundiced opinion***. In both cases that can be ***opinion of X***, but a "causative" ***by-** clause* only really works with *His opinion is **coloured by** [nostalgia, whatever]*, not *His opinion is **jaundiced by** [something]*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the Dictionary.com entry for "jaundiced," it looks like it *can* mean "jealous," but I've never seen it used that way in real life myself.  If nothing else, it's very uncommon.  Jaundice itself is a medical condition where someone has bile buildup in their blood resulting in a yellowing of the skin and a whitening of the eyes.  I know that saying someone is "green with envy" is quite a common expression, so perhaps someone thought that since yellow is kind of close to green they could use "jaundiced" as a similar idiom?  That would be my guess—but it is extremely uncommon, to my knowledge.

Comment: Oxford Dictionaries define _jaundiced_ (in its metaphorical sense) as 'characterised by bitterness, resentment or cynicism'. This usage is familiar enough to me, but it can't be used in the sense which you want. You might criticise another person as having a 'jaundiced attitude' to something they have been complaining about.